# PreUpdate annotation not firing for updating date

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data

all I am currently enrolled in a React/Spring Boot and am having trouble finding a bug that is causing my update date not to fire when I test the API using postman. Below I have two images of output from postman the first is when I create a project it correctly displays the created_At date, the second is an attempt to update the project and it works apart from updated_At never seems to be updated and is always null IN POSTMAN. When I check my h2 database however the updated_At column has the date that it was updated at.

Output when creating a project
[image]

Output when updating a project
[image]

H2 Console
[image]

Here is the code I have for my backend

Project.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Project name is required")
    private String projectName;
    @NotBlank(message ="Project Identifier is required")
    @Size(min=4, max=5, message = "Please use 4 to 5 characters")
    @Column(updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String projectIdentifier;
    @NotBlank(message = "Project description is required")
    private String description;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date start_date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date end_date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Date created_At;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date updated_At;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project")
    //
    private Backlog backlog;

    public Project() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public String getProjectIdentifier() {
        return projectIdentifier;
    }

    public void setProjectIdentifier(String projectIdentifier) {
        this.projectIdentifier = projectIdentifier;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getStart_date() {
        return start_date;
    }

    public void setStart_date(Date start_date) {
        this.start_date = start_date;
    }

    public Date getEnd_date() {
        return end_date;
    }

    public void setEnd_date(Date end_date) {
        this.end_date = end_date;
    }

    public Date getCreated_At() {
        return created_At;
    }

    public void setCreated_At(Date created_At) {
        this.created_At = created_At;
    }

    public Date getUpdated_At() {
        return updated_At;
    }

    public void setUpdated_At(Date updated_At) {
        this.updated_At = updated_At;
    }

    public Backlog getBacklog() {
        return backlog;
    }

    public void setBacklog(Backlog backlog) {
        this.backlog = backlog;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
        this.created_At = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate(){
        this.updated_At = new Date();
    }

}
```

Backlog.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Backlog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer PTSequence = 0;
    private String projectIdentifier;

    //OneToOne with project
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id",nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Project project;

    //OneToMany projecttasks


    public Backlog() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPTSequence() {
        return PTSequence;
    }

    public void setPTSequence(Integer PTSequence) {
        this.PTSequence = PTSequence;
    }

    public String getProjectIdentifier() {
        return projectIdentifier;
    }

    public void setProjectIdentifier(String projectIdentifier) {
        this.projectIdentifier = projectIdentifier;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

ProjectService.java

```
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BacklogRepository backlogRepository;

    public Project saveOrUpdateProject(Project project){
        try{
            project.setProjectIdentifier(project.getProjectIdentifier().toUpperCase());

            if(project.getId()==null){
                Backlog backlog = new Backlog();
                project.setBacklog(backlog);
                backlog.setProject(project);
                backlog.setProjectIdentifier(project.getProjectIdentifier().toUpperCase());
            }

            if(project.getId()!=null){
                project.setBacklog(backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifier(project.getProjectIdentifier().toUpperCase()));
            }

            return projectRepository.save(project);

        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new ProjectIdException("Project ID '"+project.getProjectIdentifier().toUpperCase()+"' already exists");
        }

    }


    public Project findProjectByIdentifier(String projectId){

        Project project = projectRepository.findByProjectIdentifier(projectId.toUpperCase());

        if(project == null){
            throw new ProjectIdException("Project ID '"+projectId+"' does not exist");

        }


        return project;
    }

    public Iterable<Project> findAllProjects(){
        return projectRepository.findAll();
    }


    public void deleteProjectByIdentifier(String projectid){
        Project project = projectRepository.findByProjectIdentifier(projectid.toUpperCase());

        if(project == null){
            throw  new  ProjectIdException("Cannot Project with ID '"+projectid+"'. This project does not exist");
        }

        projectRepository.delete(project);
    }

}
```

ProjectController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/api/project")
@CrossOrigin
public class ProjectController {
    // This is our controller
    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    private MapValidationErrorService mapValidationErrorService;

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createNewProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project project, BindingResult result){

        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);
        if(errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        Project project1 = projectService.saveOrUpdateProject(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<Project>(project, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{projectId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProjectById(@PathVariable String projectId) {
        Project project = projectService.findProjectByIdentifier(projectId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Project>(project, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Project> getAllProjects(){return projectService.findAllProjects();}

    @DeleteMapping("/{projectId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteProject(@PathVariable String projectId) {
        projectService.deleteProjectByIdentifier(projectId);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Project '"+projectId+"' was deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

ProjectTask.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class ProjectTask {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String projectSequence;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please include a project summary")
    private String summary;
    private String acceptanceCriteria;
    private String status;
    private Integer priority;
    private Date dueDate;
    //ManyToOne with Backlog

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String projectIdentifer;
    private Date create_At;
    private Date update_At;

    public ProjectTask() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProjectSequence() {
        return projectSequence;
    }

    public void setProjectSequence(String projectSequence) {
        this.projectSequence = projectSequence;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getAcceptanceCriteria() {
        return acceptanceCriteria;
    }

    public void setAcceptanceCriteria(String acceptanceCriteria) {
        this.acceptanceCriteria = acceptanceCriteria;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(Integer priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getProjectIdentifer() {
        return projectIdentifer;
    }

    public void setProjectIdentifer(String projectIdentifer) {
        this.projectIdentifer = projectIdentifer;
    }

    public Date getCreate_At() {
        return create_At;
    }

    public void setCreate_At(Date create_At) {
        this.create_At = create_At;
    }

    public Date getUpdate_At() {
        return update_At;
    }

    public void setUpdate_At(Date update_At) {
        this.update_At = update_At;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
        this.create_At = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate(){
        this.update_At = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProjectTask{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", projectSequence='" + projectSequence + '\'' +
                ", summary='" + summary + '\'' +
                ", acceptanceCriteria='" + acceptanceCriteria + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", priority=" + priority +
                ", dueDate=" + dueDate +
                ", projectIdentifer='" + projectIdentifer + '\'' +
                ", create_At=" + create_At +
                ", update_At=" + update_At +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to also have ProjectRepository ?

Comment: I have three project repositories. One for backlog, project and project task. Would it help to post them?